# Kafka Consumer keep getting Node Disconnected

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a kafka consumer application which I am able to start gracefully. But after consuming few messages it always shows `nodes disconnected` message and stops consuming the message . What could be the issue here ? Below is my configuration.

Is it because of the time taken by the consumer to process a single record. As per the configuration I am fetching only 5 records at a time and in my end it does not take much time to process a single record.

```
package net.abc.com;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.reactive.ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Profile("default")
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerConfigForTestTopics {
    private static final String SECURITY_PROTOCOL = "security.protocol";
    private static final String SASL_MECHANISM = "sasl.mechanism";
    private static final String SASL_JAAS_CONFIG = "sasl.jaas.config";

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;
    @Value("${kafka.username:}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${kafka.password:}")
    private String kafkaSecretPass;
    @Value("${kafka.consumer-group}")
    private String consumerGroup;

    @Value("${kafka.login-module}")
    private String loginModule;

    @Value("${kafka.security-protocol}")
    private String securityProtocol;

    @Value("${kafka.sasl-mechanism:PLAIN}")
    private String saslMechanism;

    @Value("${kafka.listener.concurrency.count:1}")
    private int concurrencyCount;


    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(String clientId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup);
        props.put(SECURITY_PROTOCOL, securityProtocol);
        props.put(SASL_MECHANISM, saslMechanism);
        props.put(SASL_JAAS_CONFIG,
                String.format("%s required username=\"%s\" password=\"%s\" ;", loginModule, username, kafkaSecretPass));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 5);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 900000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor");
        return props;
    }


    @Bean(name = "customer-group")
    public ReceiverOptions<byte[], byte[]> kafkaReceiverOptionsCustomerGroup(@Value(value = "${kafka.consumer.topic-customer-group}") String topic, KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        ReceiverOptions<byte[], byte[]> basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(consumerConfigs("customer-group-consumer"));
        return basicReceiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singletonList(topic));
    }


    @Bean(name = "customer-group-template")
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<byte[], byte[]> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplateCustomerGroup(@Qualifier("customer-group") ReceiverOptions<byte[], byte[]> kafkaReceiverOptions) {
        return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(kafkaReceiverOptions);
    }

    
   // Like this I have four listeners in this project...

}
```

Error I see.

```
[Consumer clientId=customer-group-consumer, 
groupId=abc.cdc.xyz.consumerGroup.v1] Node 25 disconnected.

[Consumer clientId=customer-group-consumer, groupId=abc.cdc.xyz.consumerGroup.v1] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=609702141, epoch=687281) to node 56:

[Consumer clientId=customer-group-consumer, groupId=abc.cdc.xyz.consumerGroup.v1] Cancelled in-flight FETCH request with correlation id 1268856 due to node 56 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 1ms, elapsed time since send: 1ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
```